# Whitescreen appears when iOS keyboard comes Up

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, ios-keyboard-extension

Using an iFrame here. 
Device : iPhone 6 and above.

I have a form. 
Whenever the iOS keyboard comes up, on clicking on any of the keys(on the keyboard), i'm getting a white screen which keeps coming from the right hand side and keeps going over and over the screen. If i keep pressing the keypad, the white screen disappears and will reappear after i keep pressing it.

Note : Whitescreen immediately disappears when keypad slides down.